# How to get vba to cycle through user defined folders instead of picking each folder manually

Tags: vba, outlook

```
Sub DeleteOld()

Dim oFolder As Folder
Dim dDate As Date
Dim ItemsOverDate As Outlook.Items
Dim dDays As Integer

Dim DateToCheck As String

dDays = InputBox("How many days?")

dDate = DateAdd("d", -dDays, Now())
dDate = Format(dDate, "dd/mm/yyyy")


Set oFolder = Application.Session.PickFolder 'or set your folder

DateToCheck = "[Received] <= """ & dDate & """"

Set ItemsOverDate = oFolder.Items.Restrict(DateToCheck)

For i = ItemsOverDate.Count To 1 Step -1
    ItemsOverDate.Item(i).Delete
Next


Set ItemsOverDate = Nothing
Set oFolder = Nothing


End Sub
```

Comment: You need to use code tags.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what your looking for.

```
Public FSO As New FileSystemObject

Private Sub DeleteOld()
MasterFolderDir = "LOCATION OF THE FOLDER THAT HOLDS ALL THE ONES YOU WANT TO DELETE"
iDate = InputBox("How many days?")
    For Each Folder In FSO.GetFolder(MasterFolderDir).SubFolders
        If DateDiff("d", Folder.DateCreated, Now) > iDate Then
            Folder.Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Let me know if it works fine for you. I didnt test it.

Answer (score 0):

You need a recursive script to drill into folders, and sub folders in those folders, and sub folders in those sub folders.

```
Sub GetFolder_Data_Collection()

Range("A:L").ClearContents
Range("A1").Value = "Name"
Range("B1").Value = "Path"
Range("C1").Value = "Size (KB)"
Range("D1").Value = "DateLastModified"
Range("E1").Value = "Attributes"
Range("F1").Value = "DateCreated"
Range("G1").Value = "DateLastAccessed"
Range("H1").Value = "Drive"
Range("I1").Value = "ParentFolder"
Range("J1").Value = "ShortName"
Range("K1").Value = "ShortPath"
Range("L1").Value = "Type"
Range("A1").Select

Dim strPath As String
'strPath = "I:\Information Security\KRI Monthly Data Collection\"
strPath = GetFolder

Dim OBJ As Object, Folder As Object, File As Object

Set OBJ = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Folder = OBJ.GetFolder(strPath)

Call ListFiles(Folder)

Dim SubFolder As Object

For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
    Call ListFiles(SubFolder)
    Call GetSubFolders(SubFolder)
Next SubFolder


End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Sub ListFiles(ByRef Folder As Object)

On Error Resume Next
For Each File In Folder.Files
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveCell = File.Name
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = File.Path
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0), Address:=File.Path, TextToDisplay:=File.Path
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) = (File.Size / 1024) 'IN KB
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3) = File.DateLastModified
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4) = File.Attributes
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5) = File.DateCreated
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6) = File.DateLastAccessed
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7) = File.Drive
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8) = File.ParentFolder
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9) = File.ShortName
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10) = File.ShortPath
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11) = File.Type
Next File

End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Sub GetSubFolders(ByRef SubFolder As Object)

Dim FolderItem As Object
On Error Resume Next
For Each FolderItem In SubFolder.SubFolders
    Call ListFiles(FolderItem)
    Call GetSubFolders(FolderItem)
Next FolderItem

End Sub


Function GetFolder() As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```